# Filter HTML in Json Response in PHP / Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I have a Controller which outputs json response & javascript function that appends that response to last tr in html table

```
<pre>
$reponse="<tr class=\"border_bottom\"><td>My Reponse</td></tr>"
echo json_encode($response);
</pre>
<b>Jquery Code:</b>
<pre>
$('table#messageslist tr.border_bottom:last').after(response)
</pre>
```

But When I append HTML it Outputs

```
 <pre>
 \\r\\n
 \\r\\n <tr>....... so on
 </pre>
```

My datatype is json
I want to remove all those `\\r \\n` I tried JSON.stringify but no effect

How can i overcome this issue

Answer (score 0):

- use str_replace ([str_replace](http://php.net/manual/de/function.str-replace.php))
- or the [preg-replace](https://www.php.net//manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

  ```
    $json_output = preg_replace("!\r?\n!", "", $json_output);
  ```

best

M